# Какую консольную программу написать?

Tags: c#

В данный момент я изучаю c# по Шилдту. Все задания для практического закрепления прочитанной теории я искал в интернете. Брал задания с лабораторных, методичек, различной литературы. Сейчас под хожу к таким темам, по которым мало что можно найти. Я думаю, выход в такой ситуации начать писать свою программу, учебный проект. После чтения определенной главы в Шилдте, пробовать реализовать прочитанную теорию в своей программе. Только я не могу придумать, что написать. На данный момент, я знаком с циклами, массивами, классами, наследованием, интерфейсами, абстрактными классами, индексаторы и свойства, исключительными ситуациями, консольный ввод-вывод в c#. Подбросьте, пожалуйста, пару вариантов какую программу можно начать писать и затем постепенно реализовывать в программе теорию из Шилдта по мере ее прочтения. **Программа должна быть консольная.**

Comment: учи UI и пиши калькулятор, разве не очевидно :DDD

Ну а если хочешь что-то посерьезнее - можешь написать простенький текстовый редактор. Сначала простенький, а потом, естественно, расширять функционал можно до бесконечности.

В контексте консольных приложений - кроме какой-то математики или, например - обвертки БД в голову ничего не лезет. Хотя можно реализовать тот-же калькулятор, а потом, когда выучишь UI - допилить код.

Comment: @AlexWindHope а как же консольные текстовые редакторы или там плееры? Если бы не чисто C#, то можно было бы попробовать какую-нибудь обертку над тем же mpd написать (вроде ncmpcpp).

Comment: ИМХО лучший в мире консольный редактор уже написан, мне было бы неинтересно =)

Comment: вот тренируйся: https://habrahabr.ru/post/312278/ и задания и разбор полетов

Answer (score 4):

1. Напиши программу, которая определяет в какой кодировке русский текст в файле.
2. Программу, которая строит таблицу определения/вызова функций для программы из нескольких файлов  с C#.
3. Набор клиент-серверных программ, определяющих производительность сетевого соединения.
4. Примерно то же для файлов (существенно разного размера) на разных дисках.
5. Для развлечения - программу печатающую собственный текст (естественно не свой исходный файл).

Для начала хватит.

Answer (score 3):

Я бы сейчас обратил внимание на алгоритмы из [элементарной теории чисел](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB#.D0.AD.D0.BB.D0.B5.D0.BC.D0.B5.D0.BD.D1.82.D0.B0.D1.80.D0.BD.D0.B0.D1.8F_.D1.82.D0.B5.D0.BE.D1.80.D0.B8.D1.8F_.D1.87.D0.B8.D1.81.D0.B5.D0.BB) и [алгоритмы сортировок](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8). Выполняя задания из этих разделов, во-первых, приобретаешь некоторый опыт в программировании и мышлении в целом, а во-вторых, закрепляешь изученный синтаксис языка и его особенности.

А вот собственно и небольшая идея: можешь сделать приложение для сортировки массивов различными алгоритмами. В консольке можешь сделать простенькое меню. Для начала делаешь базовый класс (или интерфейс), в котором есть метод сортировки. Затем, наследуя этот класс, реализовываешь разные алгоритмы (наследование + полиморфизм). Потом, так как у тебя консольный I/O, сделай так чтобы пользователи не смогли поломать твою программу (обработка исключений).

А когда дойдёшь до обобщений, можешь усовершенствовать свою программу.

Comment: 1. С какими типа данными должен работать массив? Можно все хранить в строках?

Comment: Пусть для начала хранит целые числа, ибо их сравнение - тривиальная задача. Если сортировать строки, то можно использовать разные критерии сравнения: длину, алфавит (с учётом регистра и без).

Answer (score 3):

Я сам учусь в Польше, у нас в институте давали на Си писать игры, копию total commandera(базовая функциональность), словари польско-английский и наооборот с добавлением в БД(текстовую), с возможностью поиска, с кол-вом просмотров, и реверсивным переводом, также библиотеку книг, очень распространнёный проект, на нём отточите знания классов и всего того, что с ними связано.

Мы делали это на Си.Вывод? На C# вы должны реализовать БОЛЕЕ сложную функицональность.Напишите свой файловый менеджер с функиональностью большую чем просто редактирование файлов, добавление, создание, удаление.Добавьте работу с FTP.

Либо напишиту простую консольную RPG игру, это реально и очень интересно, + развивает мозги и мышление.А после дорабатывайте проект по мере изучения языка, хотя как я понял у вас уже солидная база просто нужно отточить знания.

А вообще, я очень люблю C# ^_^.Правда книга Эндрю Троелсена мне больше понравилась.

Comment: cześć) вопрос не  по теме, так что извините...
GenchiK, может вы не подскажете, можно ли в Польше, где устроиться на работу студенту, на месяца 4-5... Набраться опыта так сказать) Есть опыт программирования в паскале, делфи, С, сейчас учу С#, дружу с photoshop, есть неплохие знания в направление WEB(cms,php,javascript)...

Comment: Привет, привет!) Давай пообщаемся там: tt.gg.1986@mail.ru либо по асе 422-041-923

Answer (score 0):

Я начинал с алгоритмов ресэмплинга с использованием полиномов Ньютона. Пользователь вводит отсчёты с консоли, потом вводит новое количество отсчётов, программа пересчитывает и выводит.